# PgRouting routing algorithm from start to end via nodes with restrictions

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have the following situation:

I want to find the shortest route from `A to B through nodes (C,D,E, etc.)` with turn directions and road type filtering.

Is there a way to accomplish this using pgRouting? Has anyone done this? I haven't begun developing anything yet, I'm just trying to find out if pgRouting is the way to go.

Thanks.

Update: The algorithm should determine the order of nodes (C,D,E, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to calculate routes via in-between nodes in pgRouting. You could try to calculate routes from A to C, A to D and so on and write an algorithm yourself using the Dijkstra shortest route algorithm.

Turn directions are not possible (as far as I know), but road type filtering can be done using a condition in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

[Turn-Restricted-Shortest-Path-(TRSP)](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/trsp/doc/index.html)
Gives me expression that it should be working or experimental option in pgRouting

Answer (score 1):

In case you still looking for more alternatives, there is another excellent (and fast) package out there called [osrm](http://project-osrm.org/) that deserves some attention.  I just found it myself, the code can be found on [github](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM)